# Twitter Bootstrap Tab-Bar bordered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styles

I have loaded twitter bootstrap and everything is working fine, I'd like to have a tab-bar with borders around the main area like so:

[image]

This is the tab-bar code:

```
<div class="span4">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">INFO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">CONTATTACI</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tabbable">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="A">
            <p>I'm in Section A.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="B">
            <p>Howdy, I'm in Section B.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="C">
            <p>What up girl, this is Section C.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- /tabbable -->
    </div>
```

I tried modifying the css to this:

```
.tabbable {
  *zoom: 1;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

But I get a border inside the tab as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/pMSMT/

What class shall I change in order to have the right result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.nav` class has a bottom margin which is creating the space between your content and the tabs.

Overwrite the bottom margin in your CSS

```
.nav{
    margin-bottom: 0px;   
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/pMSMT/1/

Comment: @NDLombardi Does this achieve what your after?

Comment: That's why. Yes, completely. Tku!

Answer (score 3):

[image]I think you should override the class of tab-content and tab-pane below solution it's work for me.

```
.tab-content {
padding: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
background: white;
border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #d9d9d9;
border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
/*  height: 300px; */
/*  overflow-y: scroll; */}

.tab-content .tab-pane {
color: #566473;}
```